# asp.net C# variables

Tags: c#, asp.net

This is probably super simple and I'm sorry if I seem totally stupid but...

I'm coding my first asp.net web page for a class and I'm used to PHP

in PHP when you create a variable in one block of code you can use it in all the others (as long as it has already be initialized)

Here is an example of what I mean:

```
<?php $myVariable = "Hello World!" ?>
```

(later on in the code:)

```
<?php echo $myVariable; ?>
```

and In PHP that will work fine

Now the equivilant in asp as I understand it is:

```
<% String myVariable = "Hello World!"; %>
```

But when I try to use it in **another** block of code, the variable myVariable is not accessible

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: This is normal, expected behavior in ASP.NET.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem here is the scope of the variable. I would suggest you to go through this article at http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=25467&seqNum=5

**Update**

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<script runat="server">
    string myVariable = "This is a variable";
</script>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <%=myVariable %>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: So, I just have to use <script> ?

Comment: @Axschech That is the standard for all non-PHP web languages

Comment: But I would suggest to use code behind approach of asp.net rather than  using the inline approach for better maintainability of code.

Comment: Thank you guys sorry I was a derp!